# .htaccess should map to index - Not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to map every URL-request (which is not a file or directory) to testindex.html

My .htaccess contains this:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . testindex.html
```

But if i try

```
    http://localhost/test/aaaaaaaa
```

then i get only a 404-Error.

Apache webserver is started and it exists a testindex.html in the test-project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `path` (because of `RewriteBase`).

Assuming your htaccess is in `test` folder, like `testindex.html`.
Replace your current code by this one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . testindex.html [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ testindex.html [L]
```

Comment: Do you definitely have mod_rewrite installed?